# Flutter: stack not aligning with widgets

Tags: flutter, image, layout

Im trying to make a filled color to be the background of a circular avatar, but for some reason it is not aligning correctly, with the circular avatar being off center from the Container. My current widget looks like this:

[image]

And code looks like this:

```
Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                        child: Center(
                            child: Stack(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              width: 180,
                              height: 180,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 228, 53, 0)),
                            ),
                            CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 40,
                                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                    state.stingrays[rowIndex]!.imageUrls[0])),
                          ],
                        )),
                      ),
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a stack to get that. You can have a container with a color and child as the circular avatar

```dart
Container(
 padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 228, 53, 0)),
     child: CircleAvatar(
      radius: 40,
      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
   state.stingrays[rowIndex]!.imageUrls[0])),
 )
```